# Checking qss syntax in C++/Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

How do I know if the qss syntax is correct? For example, i set stylesheet for widget like that:

```
widget.setStyleSheet("gdsjngsdjgsd{");
```

As we can see, qss syntax is invalid. I need get some error as QString with line number and error string when qss syntax is invalid. How i can do that?